# Group_Concat internal Group by order

Tags: mysql, sql

i have following question regarding GROUP_CONCAT():

My table has simplified following format:

```
| userId | visitTime | position |
     1       TIME1         A
     1       TIME2         B
     1       TIME3         B
     1       TIME4         B
     1       TIME5         A
     1       TIME6         C
```

With my current sql Statement:

```
Select group_concat(position) from Table where userId=1
```

I receive

A,B,B,B,A,C

How can I group the group_concat so i get a result which looks like:

```
  A,B,A,C
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I like to have the real consecutive sequence of positions, where only multiple occurrences of the same position from the next visitTime should be grouped.

EDIT2:

My expected output is **A,B,A,C**

For instance: A user 1 moves from A to B,
There he stayed at B for more than 1 entry: B, B, than he moves back to A and after that he goes to C.

I like only to get the path he used:

**From A to B to A to C**

So if a user moved to another position it should be recogniced, but he can move back again.

Comment: And based on what would you want to remove duplicate `B`'s but not duplicate `A`'s? Duplicate immediate successors/predecessors? Could you please provide a more precise description of the expected output?

Comment: See my edit 2: I like to receive the consecutive path ignoring several same positions directly behind each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to implement this you will need a unique id to show you the order of records (otherwise your request is impossible to implement). So I'm going to add an `id` column to your table like this:

```
| id | userId | visitTime | position |
  1      1       TIME1         A
  2      1       TIME2         B
  3      1       TIME3         B
  4      1       TIME4         B
  5      1       TIME5         A
  6      1       TIME6         C
```

Now the query to extract your final string:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t3.position ORDER BY t3.id)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*, ((
        SELECT position
        FROM Table
        WHERE
            id > t1.id
        AND
            userId = 1
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 1
        )) AS following_position
    FROM Table t1
    WHERE
        t1.userId = 1
) t3
WHERE
    t3.position <> t3.following_position OR t3.following_position IS NULL
```

Here's the same query without using sub-queries (I expect better performance this way but I'm not sure as there are too many NULLs in it):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t3.position ORDER BY t3.id)
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*, MIN(t2.id) AS following_id
    FROM Table t1
    LEFT JOIN Table t2 ON (t1.id < t2.id)
    WHERE
        t1.userId = 1
    AND
        (t2.userId = 1 OR t2.userId IS NULL)
    GROUP BY t1.id
) t3
LEFT JOIN Table t4 ON (t3.following_id = t4.id)
WHERE
    t3.position <> t4.position OR t4.position IS NULL
```

Comment: Nice idea, although, this solution seems to remove `C` from the result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/509cc/10 (I replaced `id` with `visitTime`)

Comment: You should add `OR t3.following_position IS NULL`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/509cc/14. Also, you should probably add an `ORDER BY` clause before the `LIMIT` to be sure that the `following_position` is correct

Comment: I was not sure if `visitTime` is unique so I introduced my own. And I didn't have MySQL to test so sorry for the problems.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I like your solution. Just thought to contribute some fixes...

Comment: Very smart solution. It also has a way better performance as the contributed solution of Lukas. BUT both solutions are quite good because i already got a few more insights in (my)sql.... Thanks all ;)

Comment: @TheBassMan: Yeah, MySQL performance with nested selects... Reminds me why I'm glad that my customers usually paid for Oracle licenses.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new query not using sub-queries. I'll be grateful if you could tell me whether the late one comes with better performance or not (I am curious myself).

Comment: @Mehran: Sorry for the delay, here the performance data on currently 1.6 M datasets in the db: Your request 1 takes 12 seconds but it gives multiple positions 6,1,3,3,3,3. Maybe it is caused by the fact that i didn't added a unique id column and used the visitTime which could be non unique in some cases. The 2nd request took >5 min. Tonight i will try to add a auto increment column on the database so hopefully the performance is better. But it seems that the correction in the application layer has a better performance...

Comment: @Lukas Eder: Thanks for the tip with Oracle i need to have a look at their products and their prices maybe it's worth ;)

Comment: @TheBassMan: Well, a very good "compromise" might be PostgreSQL, which is still free and open source.

Comment: Personally I expect a great boost when you add a primary auto-increment column. And even though I never compared MySQL with other DBMSs I can not imagine they would perform better (at least not by that much). And if you are using InnoDB make sure you know how to tune it as it has a great effect on MySQL's performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the syntax:

```
Select group_concat(distinct position order by position)
from Table
where userId=1
```

Comment: With this solution i get A,B,C not A,B,A,C ;(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't find a nice MySQL-only solution for this one.

I'd recommend doing it in your application layer.

Comment: Isn't that solution quite inefficient? I do a whole table processing on the DB after that i process the whole dataset in my application? For me it seems to be more efficient to process as much as i can on the db before i do millions of processings later

Comment: It is indeed, but only if the query is not a performance-killer. What I mean is : use your query with the `GROUP_CONCAT` and remove duplicates in your application. It should not have such a big impact.

Comment: Also an option i have to compare the performances of the different solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query (which relies on unique `visitTime` values per user...)

```
-- get those elements p1 from your table...
select p1.userId, group_concat(p1.position order by p1.visitTime)
from p p1
-- for which there doesn't exist a successor p2 with the same "position"
where not exists (
  select *
  from p p2
  where p1.userId = p2.userId
  and p1.visitTime < p2.visitTime
  and p1.position = p2.position
  -- for which there doesn't exist any record p3 strictly in between p1 and p2
  and not exists (
    select *
    from p p3
    where p2.userId = p3.userId
    and p1.visitTime < p3.visitTime
    and p2.visitTime > p3.visitTime
  )
)
group by p1.userId
```

See a demo in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/509cc/7).

Note, in other databases, you would probably use window functions, such as `LEAD() OVER()` and `LAG() OVER()` instead of writing the above monster...

Comment: Thanks this query gives for the example the correct result! Now i have to check it with my dataset.

Comment: @TheBassMan: Great! I've updated the query to do things for all users, not just for one. It seems like a more general solution like that